# Editing text in a file using a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to edit some lines of text within a text file using a batch file. The lines are as below -

```
#TEST_RSA_KEY=1
#V3SERVER0=109.73.122.107;29006
#DOWNLOAD0=109.73.122.112;29006
```

I need to change these to be

```
#TEST_RSA_KEY=0
#V3SERVER0=91.207.36.31;29006
#DOWNLOAD0=91.207.36.37;29006
```

How would you recommend I do this via a batch file, I am very new to this and have very basic knowledge so simple and clear answers please! :) Thank you

Comment: Always you want to modify that file with same content?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Not tested

```
@echo off

set file_loc=C:\text.file.txt

for "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%a in ("%file_loc%") do (
   set "%%a"
)

set "#TEST_RSA_KEY=0"
set "#V3SERVER0=91.207.36.31;29006"
set "#DOWNLOAD0=91.207.36.37;29006"

set #>"%file_loc%"
```

I've assumed that all properties start with `#`

Answer (score 0):

*Note - I have not tested any of the code examples below, so there could be bugs. But I have successfully used all of the techniques below in the past, and any fixes (if necessary) should be fairly trivial.*

All of my solutions below assume that spaces never appear in any of the name value pairs. Each of the solutions could be adapted to support spaces, if necessary.

If the order of the lines is not important, then the following pure batch solution works well and is quite fast. I use FINDSTR to remove the lines that are to be altered, before appending the new values to the end:

```
@echo off
>"file.txt.new" (
  findstr /v /b "#TEST_RSA_KEY= #V3SERVER0= #DOWNLOAD0=" "file.txt" 
  echo #TEST_RSA_KEY=0
  echo #V3SERVER0=91.207.36.31;29006
  echo #DOWNLOAD0=91.207.36.37;29006
)
move /y "file.txt.new" "file.txt" >nul
```

If the order of the lines is important, then I would use my [JREPL.BAT utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) - a hybrid JScript/batch regular expression text processor. It is pure script that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward. I recommend putting the script within a directory that is listed within your path. I like to use "c:\utils" for all my non-standard utilities.

A simple one replacement at a time strategy is the simplest effective solution, and it should be plenty fast unless the file is exceptionally large:

```
@echo off
call jrepl "^(#TEST_RSA_KEY)=.*" "$1=0"                  /f "file.txt" /o -
call jrepl "^(#V3SERVER0)=.*"    "$1=91.207.36.31;29006" /f "file.txt" /o -
call jrepl "^(#DOWNLOAD0)=.*"    "$1=91.207.36.37;29006" /f "file.txt" /o -
```

The above strategy can be made easy to maintain (add additional replacements) with a bit more code, as long as none of the strings contain `*` or `?`, and no value begins with `=`:

```
@echo off
for %%A in (
  "#TEST_RSA_KEY=0"
  "#V3SERVER0=91.207.36.31;29006"
  "#DOWNLOAD0=91.207.36.37;29006"
) do for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%B in (%%A) do (
  call jrepl "^(%%B)=.*" "$1=%%C" /f "file.txt" /o -
)
```

The `*` and `?` limitation can be removed if the replacement strings are already in a separate file (replace.txt):

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%A in (replace.txt) do (
  call jrepl "^(%%A)=.*" "$1=%%B" /f "file.txt" /o - 
)
```

Or the replacement strings could be embedded within the batch script itself

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%A in ('findstr "^#" "%~f0"') do (
  call jrepl "^(%%A)=.*" "$1=%%B" /f "file.txt" /o - 
)
exit /b

#TEST_RSA_KEY=0
#V3SERVER0=91.207.36.31;29006
#DOWNLOAD0=91.207.36.37;29006
```

The entire job can be done much more efficiently in one pass if you are willing to do the capture group bookkeeping and prepare a long command line (8191 byte length max):

```
@call jrepl "(#TEST_RSA_KEY)=.* (#V3SERVER0)=.* (#DOWNLOAD0)=.*" "$2=0 $4=91.207.36.31;29006 $6=91.207.36.37;29006" /b /t " " /f "file.txt" /o -
```

A variation of any of the prior 3 methods could be used to make this efficient solution easier to maintain, as long as `!` never appears in the values. For example:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "find="
set "repl="
set "n=0"
for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%A in ('findstr "^#" "%~f0"') do (
  set "find=!find! (%%A)=.*"
  set /a n+=2
  set "repl=!repl! $!n!=%%B"
)
call jrepl "!find:~1!" "!repl:~1!" /b /t " " /f "file.txt" /o - 
exit /b

#TEST_RSA_KEY=0
#V3SERVER0=91.207.36.31;29006
#DOWNLOAD0=91.207.36.37;29006
```